# Subscriptions Addon is not working in Expression Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine, add-on

I purchased subscription addon from [here](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions), but its not working I have successfully installed it and its showing in my admin panel but when i write below code its not showing anything to me on my page.

```
{exp:subs:subscribe register_member="yes" plan="{segment_3}" payment_method="stripe" return="/account/subscription/%SUBS_HASH%"}

<h1>Subscribe to: {subs:plan:label}</h1>
<p>
    Every <strong>{subs:plan:recurring_interval_count} {subs:plan:recurring_interval}</strong> {subs:plan:recurring_amount} {subs:plan:currency}
</p>
<hr>

{if subs:total_errors}
<ul class="errors">
    {subs:form_errors}
    <li>{subs:error}</li>
    {/subs:form_errors}
</ul>
{/if}

<h3>Credit Card</h3>

<label>Credit Card Number</label>
<input name="card_number" type="text" value="{subs:card_number}">

<label>Name on card</label>
<input name="card_name" type="text" value="{subs:card_name}">

<label>Expires</label>
<select name="card_exp_month">{subs:month_options}</select>
<select name="card_exp_year">{subs:year_options}</select>         

<label>Security Code</label>
<input name="card_cvc" type="text" value="{subs:card_cvc}" size="5">


<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>

{/exp:subs:subscribe}
```

I used their example code you can find it [here](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/subs-subscribe/).

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: If you bought it, doesn't some form of support not follow? Have you tried to poke the ones who sold you this?

Comment: @Epodax they are not replying I have already tried.

Comment: Suggest you post on the ExpressionEngine specific Stack Exchange site, you may have a better response. DevDemon are normally really good with their support, did you use their support link? http://www.devdemon.com/support/ Also Note: "ALL PURCHASES COME WITH 90 DAYS OF FREE SUPPORT." So outside of that they may ignore you!

Comment: @PeterLewis I purchased it three days ago 2 times I have contact them via their support panel but they are not responding one more issue with their hits addon really  devdemon.com provides very worst service and cheap quality addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is showing blank because page is not getting {segment_3} i.e. plan i hope you have not create any plan or if created then you have not passed them as {segment_3}. To test this thing use below code it will be helpful for you.

```
{exp:subs:subscribe register_member="yes" plan="gold" payment_method="stripe" return="/account/"}

<h1>Subscribe to: {subs:plan:label}</h1>
<p>
    Every <strong>{subs:plan:recurring_interval_count} {subs:plan:recurring_interval}</strong> {subs:plan:recurring_amount} {subs:plan:currency}
</p>
<hr>

{if subs:total_errors}
<ul class="errors">
    {subs:form_errors}
    <li>{subs:error}</li>
    {/subs:form_errors}
</ul>
{/if}

{if logged_out}
<h3>User Account</h3>

<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="">

<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" value="">

<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="">

<label>Password Confirm</label>
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="">
{/if}


<h3>Credit Card</h3>

<label>Credit Card Number</label>
<input name="card_number" type="text" value="{subs:card_number}">

<label>Name on card</label>
<input name="card_name" type="text" value="{subs:card_name}">

<label>Expires</label>
<select name="card_exp_month">{subs:month_options}</select>
<select name="card_exp_year">{subs:year_options}</select>         

<label>Security Code</label>
<input name="card_cvc" type="text" value="{subs:card_cvc}" size="5">

<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>

{/exp:subs:subscribe}
```

make a plan named gold or abc whatever you want must put the same name at plan="plan_name" at the first line you can see it and remember for Visa cards it requires some more fields you may get fields error for this you have to use that fields you can find those fields on devdemon website.

enjoy !!!

Comment: ah.. thank you Ravi how this stupid thing i did you are right Ravi i forgot to pass {segment_3} thank you so much.....